# How do static constructors for generic types work?

Tags: c#, generics, compiler-construction

```
public abstract class EventSystemBase<T, K> : IAutoEvent
    where T : Event
    where K : IAutoEvent, new()
{
    public static T Instance { get { return EventSystem.Events.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault(); } }
    public static IAutoEvent AutoEventInstance { get { return new K(); } }

    static EventSystemBase()
    {
        EventBot.Register(new EventBotEntry(Instance.Name, AutoEventInstance));
    }

    [...]
}
```

I don't really understand how this compiles.

- When does the static constructor run?
- Why can I use generic types in static members?
- How is it supposed to know which types to apply?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The static constructor is *at the first moment it is needed*. The exact timing is a bit tricky because if flags like `beforefieldinit` in the binary; you probably don't need to worry too much about the details except that it's run when the first class member is accessed, before it is needed.
- Well, why not? :) Every type of the form `EventSystemBase<T, K>` is its *own* separate class and bears *no relation* to the other generic instances of the class, so the constructor needs to run for each one. They're all different to the runtime in all* respects.
- The static constructor runs for a "cooked" type and *not* the "raw" type (i.e. it runs for the version *with* the generic types substituted), so there's no real problem here.

*Actually, the runtime avoids creating duplicate instances of reference type generics. But that doesn't matter here, to the programmer or to the program.

Answer (score 2):

The static constructor isn't for the open generic type. It will only run when you have specified the type paramaters, e.g., `EventSystemBase<MyEvent, MyAutoEvent>`, which is actually a different class than e.g., `EventSystemBase<AnotherEvent, MyAutoEvent>` with its *own* static constructor. In *each* case, the static constructor runs before the first instance of that separate class is created or any of its static members are referenced.

Comment: actually from what I'm testing, it appears static members in the base class Foo<T> are shared by Foo<int> and Foo<string>

Comment: `class Foo<T> {public static int x = 0;}` `Foo<int>.x = 10;` `Console.WriteLine(Foo<string>.x) //still zero`

Answer (score 1):

If it applies the same from my c++ knowledge back in the day...

<strike>Generics are generated at compile time</strike>, and they are converted into many *seperate and distinct* classes. For each of theses classes, the static constructor runs before any code references the static class. The CLR knows which types to reference because each of the classes are *unique*.

EventSystemBase<*string*, *byte*> has absolutely no relationship with EventSystemBase<*string*, *int*>. It is as if you have written two entirely separate classes in your source code.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myInt = new MyGeneric<int>();
        myInt.InstanceMethod();
        MyGeneric<int>.StaticMethod();

        MyGeneric<long>.StaticMethod();
        var myLong = new MyGeneric<long>();
        myLong.InstanceMethod();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class MyGeneric<T>
{
    static MyGeneric()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static constructor: {0}", typeof(T).Name);
    }

    public static void StaticMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static method: {0}", typeof(T).Name);
    }

    public void InstanceMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instance method: {0}", typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Generics are NOT generated at compile time!

Comment: C# generics work differently than C++ templates despite similar syntax.

Comment: other than the compilation bit, it's correct? Also, they removed my carets for anti-xss... otherwise my second to last sentence would have made more sense :(

Comment: Aside from that, it's fairly accurate.

Answer (score 0):

1. The static constructor on the generic is invoked each time you invoke a different < T,K> generic class.

2-3. with 1 it should be clear, it is releated to the T,K generic